# How do properly place code into the build/generated folder

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, code-generation

I'm trying to figure out a good way to generate code on build and move it into the proper build/generated folder.

This is an Android project, in Android Studio, built with gradle. My project has two modules.

The first module is a pure Java module. It has an input file and then some code which reads the input file and spits out generated code based on the input file.

The second module is an Android module and uses the classes that the first one generates.

Right now I'm just running the generation module manually and it writes the class files into the Android module's source code. However I want to change this so that:

1. It runs the generation code automatically whenever I build the Android module
2. The generated code is placed into the Android modules build/generated folder like normal generated code.

I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this. Most examples seem to be around annotation processing which this isn't. I assume it would be something I would setup in the Android module's build.gradle. I could do a gradleTask and manually write it into the build/generated folder but is there some standard mechanism for knowing what directory structure to use?

What would be the correct approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Write a Gradle plugin. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Gradle/PluginStub) for a stub plugin, and [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Gradle/Staticizer) for a plugin that uses JavaPoet to code-generate a Java class based on a JSON file, where the Java class goes into `build/generated/`. FWIW, those projects are covered in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/writing-a-gradle-plugin) and [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/code-generation) of one of my books.